# Why doesn't the draggable end up under the mouse?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, dock

The draggable does not undock under the mouse, but rather all the way to the left-hand margin of the container.  Why?

1. Go to jsfiddle example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Trober/URudt/23/)

   `Some fake code here, too long to publish inline` 
   ​
2. Drag the draggable to the north side of the container.  It will indicate via a blue dashed line and "Snapping North!" message above the container it is going to dock against the north side.  When it does, drop it.
3. Now drag the docked panel away from the north side.

Problem: the draggable does not unsnap under the mouse, rather stays flush with the left-hand side.

Can you make it unsnap where it drags under the mouse?

Comment: Never got an answer.  :-(